# Jaxb and unordered set with separate lists for every element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I have a xml schema with a sequence.

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="x"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="y"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

In this case all `x`'s must occur before all `y`'s.
That is not what i want. So i tried choice but when using this, all x's and y's are mapped in on list when i generate the corresponding class.

Is there a way to have separate lists for x's and y's with no special order in the xml?

Comment: what class structure are you getting currently? please describe it here

Answer (score 0):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations are quite forgiving on the order of XML elements when unmarshalling.  I will demonstrate below with an example.

**Root**

Below is a domain object with separate `List` properties.

```
package forum11519412;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    List<String> x;
    List<Integer> y;

}
```

**input.xml**

Below is a sample XML document where the `List` items are mixed up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <y>1</y>
    <x>A</x>
    <y>2</y>
    <x>B</x>
    <y>3</y>
    <x>C</x>
</root>
```

**Demo**

The demo code will unmarshal `input.xml` and marshal it back out.

```
package forum11519412;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11519412/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

In the resulting XML, the contents will appear ordered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <x>A</x>
    <x>B</x>
    <x>C</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <y>2</y>
    <y>3</y>
</root>
```

Comment: I believe you have a good final answer that models the result that was asked for, but OP is looking for for a way to generate the Root you provide from his XSD. Some kind of xjc binding magic, I believe, is what is being asked for. Authoring classes by hand, ignoring the schema, is bad news.

Comment: You are the author. Well. I for one was expecting xjc  made classes.